# Snowflake Convert 12H timezone to 24H timezone

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am writing SQL to convert 12H timezone value to 24H timezone value.

This is the original dataset, both two columns are VARCHAR type:

[image: original data]

I want to combine these two columns and make it to this format: "2021-01-31 23:42:07" of TIMESTAMP_NTZ type

I tried this query:

```
  SELECT
  TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(
  TO_VARCHAR(
  TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss aa', CONCAT(DATE, ' ', TIME))
   , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  ) AS timestamp_column
 FROM FCT_LYTX_CAMERA_EVENT;
```

However I got this error message:

> Can't parse 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss aa' as timestamp with format '2021-01-31 11:42:07 PM'

Looking for a SQL expert to help find the right way to do this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are making error calling the function [`to_timestamp`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp), *string_expression* should be the first parameter :

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE, ' ', TIME), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS PM')
```

You can directly do :

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CONCAT(DATE, ' ', TIME), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS PM')
```

The format should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **hh** that represent 12-hour format, you need to replace it with **HH** for 24-hour format:

Line needs to change:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM', CONCAT(DATE, ' ', TIME)),
```

Comment: Hi Maninder, thank you for replying, I tried this but still got this error: Can't parse 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM' as timestamp with format '2021-01-31 11:42:07 PM'. the original data is in 12-hour format and I want to convert it to 24-hour format

Comment: Can you please give a try with:

TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss aa', CONCAT(DATE, ' ', TIME)),

Comment: Hi, this one works 'YYYY-MM-DD hh12:mi:ss AM', and I also made another mistake which is that I put the string expression to the second parameter (like what the guy answered above), thank you for your help!